# Failed to compile module vmmon vmware

Tags: linux, debian, vmware

I'm going to install `VMware` 8 on `debian` 6 with 3.2.xx `kernel`. I've installed it thoroughly and it seemed that there wasn't any error in installing process.but when I want to run `VMware workstation` it got an error which says:

```
Failed to compile module vmmon
```

what is the cause of this error and how can I solve it?

**log ouput:**

```
2012-10-11T19:29:37.521+03:30| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only$
2012-10-11T19:29:39.324+03:30| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmmon!
```

Comment: Have you upgraded your kernel recently ?

Comment: yes, I've installed kernel 3.2.xx from backports packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I user this commands to solve my problem:

```
# cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules;
# wget http://pavlinux.ru/vmware/8.0.0/source.tar.lzma;
# tar -xf source.tar.lzma;
# vmware-modconfig --console --install-all;
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I always need to use this command on my Ubuntu 13.04 box, even with latest VMWare Player.

Comment: the link is broken. `pavlinux.ru` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run this command as `root` after each `kernel` upgrades :

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: thank you sputnick, I did it and again same problem with vmmon.

Answer (score 1):

Solved in this way

Check your version `$ vmplayer -v` to insert in the script, in my case is 14.1.7

```
$ vim vmware-repair.sh
```

press i and paste

```
#!/bin/bash
VMWARE_VERSION=workstation-14.1.7 #This needs to be the actual name of the appropriate branch in mkubecek's GitHub repo for your purposes
TMP_FOLDER=/tmp/patch-vmware
rm -fdr $TMP_FOLDER
mkdir -p $TMP_FOLDER
cd $TMP_FOLDER
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git #Use `git branch -a` to find all available branches and find the one that's appropriate for you
cd $TMP_FOLDER/vmware-host-modules
git checkout $VMWARE_VERSION
git fetch
make
sudo make install
sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
systemctl restart vmware && vmplayer &
```

Press ESC then :wq then ENTER

```
$ chmod +x vmware-repair.sh
$ sudo ./vmware-repair.sh
```

[Source](https://wesley.sh/solved-vmware-workstation-15-fails-to-compile-kernel-modules-with-failed-to-build-vmmon-and-failed-to-build-vmnet/)

Answer (score 1):

This could help future users with the same problem

```
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
cd vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-16.2.3
sudo make ; sudo make install
```